# Is there an equivalent to parse to use before syncing with the server?

Tags: backbone.js

In my backbone model, I parse the response from the server:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/users",
    parse: function(response){
        var data = {};
        data.id = reponse.userDetails.id;
        data.name = response.userDetails.firstname + " " + response.userDetails.lastname;
        data.description = response.userDetails.description;

        return data;
    }
});

var myModel = new MyModel({id: 1});
myModel.fetch();
```

The views that use this model can manipulate it, for example, if the user were to click on the view to "select" it, it would update the model...

```
myModel.set({selected: true});
```

...and the view would re-render based on the model's change event and highlight the "selected" user.

When it comes time to save the model to the server, how do I only send the attributes the server wants? and ignore the attributes which were added through user interaction.

OR

Should the data model always reflect what the server returns? If so, is there a better way to store the user interactions (whether the view is "selected")? Should it be a separate model than the actual data model?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The model doesn't need to mirror the data on the server if that doesn't make sense for your application.

For the model's attributes, if you don't need to render those attributes in a template, then you can just override [`model.toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) to only serialize the attributes you want sent to the server. Be careful though, in this case if you are rendering your template (or anything else) using `this.model.toJSON()` then it will also be affected. If that's a problem then you can override [`model.sync()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync) instead and manipulate the data passed in before sending it to `Backbone.sync`. For example:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function (method, model, options) {
    // remove the unwanted attributes. Something like...
    options.attrs = _.pick(model.attributes, 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3');
    return Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
  }
});
```

Comment: Or better, leave `toJSON` for server communication (as the standard JSON libraries expect that method) and add another method for preparing things for views. Then `toJSON` can mirror `parse` and you can have another method which does the usual `_(this.attributes).clone()` for your views (that's all the standard `toJSON` does anyway).

Comment: I think the overridden sync() method should first look at the data in options.attr, then fallback to model.attributes. Backbone.sync() tries to get the data from options.data, then options.attr, then finally model.attributes. If you always cram all the model attributes into options.attr, this breaks the ability to only save changed model attributes. http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-177

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `model.toJSON` as suggested by mu_is_too_short worked nicely for me.

**In the model**

```
function() {
    var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
    json.ExtendedFieldData = JSON.stringify(json.ExtendedFieldData);
    return json;
},
```

We use `model.attributes` for templates.

Comment: This breaks if you use Marionette, which calls model.toJSON() to get the data to pass into the template. Better to override model.sync().

Comment: `toJSON` can receive options, so you could deal with both cases inside it. (Maybe not as easily in Marionette, I don't know, I don't use it)